# Calculate in media queries with SCSS

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

Is it possible to calculate in `media queries` when using `SCSS` and a variable?

I would like to assign a value to a breakpoint variable and in some cases calculate `+ 1` directly in the media query `SCSS` file like this:

```
$bp-xl: 1024px;

@media (min-width: $bp-xl + 1) { ... } /* MIN-WIDTH = 1025px */
```

So my new min-width would be `1025px`.

Comment: You can perform operations inside the variable call, so `@media (min-width: #{$bp-xl + 1}) { ... }` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It's Possible!
Have a look for Demo! https://codepen.io/navdeepsingh/pen/qpejKo

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 12px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

$bp-xl: 1024px;

@media (min-width: $bp-xl + 6) { 
  h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background: pink;
    color: black;
  }
} /* MIN-WIDTH = 1030px */
```

```html
<h1>HELLO</h1>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `calc(#{$bp-xl} + 1px);`. `calc` does the calcuation, the `#{}` is string interpolation, which lets you insert a variable into `calc`